# My Cube is falling through my Plan

Tags: modeling, physics

I changed the speed of my animation in the scene propertys/rigid body world from 1.000 to 10.000 and now my cube is falling through the plane even I set the plane on passive and the cube on active with collision enabled. What am I doing wrong?

Thx in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select your rock

tap CTRL-A -> scale

then it works.

explanation: whenever you do something with physics, always(!) apply scale and rotation, else it won't work or works weird.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this does not change anything :( Event with the max setting of 32767. Whats the purpose of the Substeps? What do they do?

Comment: Ok, then please provide your blend files. Else we can just guess what it might be.

Comment: Okay thank you for your fast reply. How can I provide my blend file? I dont see the option if i edit my question.

Comment: open this https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: Done! :) Would be nice if you could check it

Comment: checked, answer updated. Happy blending!

Comment: Thank you very much mister :) and have a good day!

Comment: Please check the checkmark on the left side of my answer! Thank you and dito!

Comment: :( im sorry one more problem it works fine in edit mode but in the object mode when my elevation is applied it still goes through the plane

Comment: you must have done something else in between. Download your file from here again, select your rock, press CTRL-A (in object mode) and choose scale. Run your animation. it works. and what do you mean by "elevation applied"!? you should apply your scale.

Comment: what blender version are you using?

Comment: 2.92. !   Okay sorry i forgot to tell you that I used the Blender GIS Plugin in between to get the elevation data from google maps. After this step the animation does not work anymore

Comment: i don't know this plugin and i don't know what it does. I just know...with my steps your animation works. Sorry.

Comment: U should try it its fantastic you can choose an area from google maps and blender creates automatically  a 3D model with elevation from it. Hm its seems to be an really complicated error if even you cant solve it. :O

Comment: Ok, then give me your blend file with plug-in and the „new“ problem

Comment: And the link to the plug-in please

Comment: https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS

Comment: the blend file is the same as before because i just applied the elevation with the gis plugin

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry but I don't want to install that plugin... but have you generated real geometry with it or is it just a modifier or something similar so that the rigid body doesn't "know" that the elevation is there?

Comment: ...and can it be that the displacement maps are missing in the file? The ones needed for the elevation?

Comment: hey sorry for the late respond. Yes but why are the displacement maps missing? and I think that it generates a plane with a google maps texture material on it and afterwarfs it takes the google elevation data to generate a 3D Model.